# Error with transaction not successfully mined in block while deploying a contract on Kadena Chainweaver: Gas Error Gas limit(600) exceeded

Tags: blockchain

[Gas fees and units used when deployed contract:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrYxS.png)

[Error shown: Failure: Gas Error: Gas limit(600) exceeded: 601](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WmeK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to increase my gas limit to 3000 to solve this.

In KDA, like others blockchains, each operation consumes gas.
Thus a transaction consumes a total gas amount depending on its complexity.
The gasLimit is max gas you want to spend for that transaction.
If it is too low, the transaction will fail (this is what happened in your case),
if it it too high, you will be refunded at the end of transaction.

Contract deployment is an heavy transaction, thus it cost a lot of gas.
Gas Limit setting of 600 is fine for a coin transfer, but not enough for a contract deployment.
3000 Units Gas limit is recommended at the moment for contract deployment.

[Contract Deployment with enough Units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt0oZ.png)